# NIC Teaming or MPIO for SAN

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2019

I've been looking online on best practice. I have brand new Windows Server 2019 Datacenter installed on my host machine. I am trying to setup something new (in our environment) which is not new to the world I would like to provide high availability for our storage, to store VMs on a CSV. I have two separate 10 Gbps cards. **My question is when I set this up and when setting up iSCSI, should I setup NIC Team in server manager for my storage network or should I have two separate cards with separate IPs and turn on MPIO?** I am seeing articles about this but most articles are outdated and talk about Windows Server 2012 R2 when technology was not as mature as it is today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for MPIO if your backend can handle this because this gives you two separate queues for handling the traffic while teaming does NOT.